# FFmpeg-Unable to find a suitable output format for FONTCONFIG_FILE

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using below ffmpeg command to draw text on top of video-

```
String path=getFilesDir()+"/fonts.conf";
String[] complexCommand ={"-i", inputFilePath,"FONTCONFIG_FILE="+path,"-vf","drawtext=fontfile=/assets/fonts/formataregular.otf: \\text='Stack Overflow: fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2'","-codec:a","copy",outputFilePath};
```

I am using [WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android) and i have followed instruction-

> If you want to use FONTCONFIG then you need to specify your custom
>   fontconfig config file (e.g - "FONTCONFIG_FILE=/sdcard/fonts.conf
>   ./ffmpeg --version", where /sdcard/fonts.conf is location of your
>   FONTCONFIG configuration file)

My configuration file is stored in Internal Storage of device with name `fonts.conf`

I am getting below error-

> Unable to find a suitable output format for
>   'FONTCONFIG_FILE=/data/data/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor/files/fonts.conf'
>                                                                                         FONTCONFIG_FILE=/data/data/videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor/files/fonts.conf:
>   Invalid argument

I also tried path as-

```
  File dir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  String path=dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/fonts.conf";
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: That's an environment variable to be exported; not a ffmpeg command argument.

Comment: @Mulvya how can i do tht?